# Best method to load third party Svelte components at runtime

Tags: javascript, svelte

Is it possible to compile a component to be remotely fetched at runtime? This is not about routes and SSR, but allowing a third party to develop extensions (which would be loaded at runtime) for the main app.

I have heard that one way to accomplish this would be to compile the component as a custom element (then it can be loaded and injected to the dom dynamically).

Is it possible to do it without using custom elements? To just compile it as a single Svelte component, which can be loaded at runtime in a Svelte app?

Comment: It seems to be possible with https://github.com/sveltejs/component-template
dist/index.js can be loaded dynamically and then the component can be rendered like this: https://svelte.dev/docs#Creating_a_component